# Vertical align center text on Label Inside ActionItem

Tags: css, angular, nativescript

I have the following code that display a font icon inside ActionItem

```
<ActionBar title="List" class="action-bar">
    <ActionItem ios.position="right" (tap)="showMenu()">
        <Label [text]="'ion-android-more-horizontal' | fonticon"  class="ion c-white large" android:width="35"></Label>
    </ActionItem>
</ActionBar>
```

After upgrading to v3 on android I have the text not centerd like the image below.

[image]

I tried some css style but seem has no effect.

Any one has an idea how to fix this properly or confirm it's {N} Bug.

Comment: Excuse me, you want to vertically align the icon with the text "genymotion pour..."?

Comment: the '...' icon should appear on same line like the titel List

Comment: If they are both in the same block, try using `vertical-align: middle;` to the icon.

Comment: style="vertical-align: middle;" on label has no effect